# Intelligent Question Routing

Tags: feature-request, experts

Is there any work going on to try to put questions in front of the best people to answer them?

As an example, when somebody like John Resig logs on, it should be very easy for him to see a few jQuery questions that are most in need of his help. Ideally, they would be the most "important" questions, perhaps defined by the question having more upvotes than any answers, and should all be inferred automatically without the system having to know that he created jQuery, but the idea of people being able to "vote" that a certain user take a look at a question is neat too.

Another variation of this feature is putting answers in front of people that might be able to improve them. Again, if an answer has been accepted but hasn't gotten as many upvotes as the question, perhaps it needs some love from an expert.

Answer (score 4):

"Interested Tags." Things like this should be opt-in. I should seek out PHP/jQuery questions, you shouldn't hunt me down with them :) SO has to be a hobby, a labor of love, not a job. Most of us are already given a todo-list every morning :)

Comment: Sure, but it's an issue of time management.  There are 1000s of questions in popular tags.  If somebody like carmack or resig logged in, wouldn't you want them to spend their time as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Solution:             VV

Comment: I would want them to spend their time however they want to spend it. If they want to answer CSS questions for the day, fine. We can't enforce mandates on people based upon what they are known for.

Comment: (Those were arrows pointing at my answer)

Comment: I'm not talking about enforcing anything, and I'm not sure where you are getting that from.  I'm talking about suggestions.  There are already a bunch of tabs on my user page.  How about another one with a list of questions that the system has determined I might have some unique insight on?

Comment: Yeah, the one I linked too...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/intelligent-question-routing/8609#8609

Comment: @twk That's what the 'interested tags' are for. You explicitly state what type of questions you are interested in.

Comment: Or, you go to the Unanswered Questions page and sort them by my tags...

Comment: Jonathan -- there are 39 pages of unanswered questions in a single one of my interested tags, c++.  I don't have time to look through all those and see which ones I know something about.  It would be helpful to me if some kind of machine learning/filtering could be applied to that list to only show me ones similar to ones that I've answered before.  Would that not be helpful to you?  

Whether or not this is a worthwhile use of developer time is another issue.  Personally, I'm hoping some grad student takes the SO dumps and tries to tackle the problem.

Comment: Add more tags that you are interested in.  It will help filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

In the unanswered questions page, questions are sorted by tags that you have previously participated in.  That is the closest we have right now.

It's [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags).

Instead of sorting by the tags you have selected as interesting, it used to sort by tags that you had previously participated it.  I think I liked that better.

Comment: fixed my link                   .

Comment: That page is a good start, but there are too many questions for me in there.  Again, 39 pages of stuff.  Which ones am I most uniquely suited to answer?  I don't know!  It would be interesting for a more complex algorithm to show me the top 5 questions it thinks I should answer.

Comment: Like i said, you shoudl request that it sorts it by tags you have participated in instead of what id does now.  It used to work better.