# How to ask a question to a particular user of stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you contact a StackOverflow user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16757/how-do-you-contact-a-stackoverflow-user)
>   [Routing a Question to a Particular SO Member or Members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-so-member-or-members)

Hai guys,
    How to ask a question to a particular user of stackoverflow.com .... Is there any way...

Comment: duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-so-member-or-members

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16757/how-do-you-contact-a-stackoverflow-user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless the user has put their contact details (email address or blog details) into their profile I think you can safely assume they don't wish to be contacted by other Stack Overflow users.

You could try leaving a comment asking them to contact you under one of their posts and they might get back to you.

Comment: ...if you're lucky.

Comment: Thanks kev i ll try to do so...