# Asking specific people to answer my questions

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Routing a Question to a Particular SO Member or Members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-so-member-or-members)

How can I ask/notify some specific person that I know is a specialist for my question? This person is registered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This has been discussed multiple times: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-so-member-or-members http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41474/request-a-specific-expert-on-a-subject-to-answer-your-question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30564/how-to-ask-a-question-to-a-particular-user-of-stackoverflow-com

Comment: sorry, should I delete my question then?

Comment: This will never, ever happen. People would get swamped with requests.

Comment: maybe people willing to answer can agree to be notified? later, if they got bored, they just switch this feature off.

Comment: People who are "willing" already have a variety of feature which make it easy to find questions in *"their"* tags: interested tag, the front-page selection algorithm, and RSS feeds.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to say that unless they've already posted on the question, you can't notify them via the system.

Send them a message or email if you know them outside the site. If you don't, hope they see your question. This would be a bad idea in the long-run because people would be able to spam those users with higher reputation to answer all their questions. It's an annoyance over anything else.

Comment: maybe people willing to answer can agree to be notified? later, if they got bored, they just switch this feature off.