# Refer the question to someone else

Tags: feature-request, questions, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Routing a Question to a Particular SO Member or Members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-so-member-or-members)

Often, a particular question involves a two-three members ensuing a discussion but someone within the community may be better able to help but has not seen the question. In such case, is it possible to involve (or to bring to notice of) someone by referring the question to him/her.

Thanks

Comment: Find their email address, email them a link to the question.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Add a comment and tag their username.</del>

However, I would not suggest always doing this, as many times there are other people who might be able to answer your question who you might not know of.

Comment: I think the tagging only works if the user has participated in the question already.

Comment: @Kate, correct. I misread the question, I thought it was about getting the attention of one of the 2-3 members.