# How about mentioning someone in my question? / making a followup question

Tags: feature-request, questions, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Routing a Question to a Particular SO Member or Members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-so-member-or-members)
>   [Refer the question to someone else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85067/refer-the-question-to-someone-else)

1. I want to ask a co-worker a professional question. I post the question on StackOverflow and mention him (like twitters @hisName) in the quesion , or in a special input box , like a a tag - then he gets a notification that he was asked a question , and can answer it - but everybody get to learn from it (same goes to just someone I think will know the answer , i.e , @Jeff Atwood )
2. Second scenario : I see a question that is very similar to mine , but not exactly , and the user who asked it might be able to help me with my follow up question . So I either mention him , or open a "followup" question , that both the original poster and the user that got most votes / accepted answer get a notification that someone asked a followup question.

Comment: Feature request : Burninate all who preface their titles with tags

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't - Maybe he learned english from HK-47?

Comment: Sorry to infuriate everyone here , but I think you misunderstood what I was suggesting. The point was that instead of going to a co-worker (And if you haven't been around lately , sometimes your co-worker is in a different time zone then you) and keeping the knowledge just between him and me - Posting it on SO would enable other people as well to profit from it. 
Regarding the second point - this is not a "Personal message" . It's an invitation to answer , and you don't have to take it. It will probably increase participation.

Comment: And even if you totally don't like my suggestion - that's totally ok, but you're acting like jerks.

Answer (score 12):

1) He's your coworker. Email him. Send him an instant message. *Walk over to his cubicle.* You have enough avenues for notifying him as it is, you don't need this website to act as another one of those means. By all means, *ask* the question on Stack Overflow if you feel it adds value, but you don't need Stack Overflow in order to talk to your coworker.

2) More generally, we do not want people addressing questions to *specific people.* Ask your question and let the community answer it. More often than not, you'll get the answer you need from the hundreds or thousands of active users following a given tag, and it may indeed be the individual that you would like to review your question. And if you *truly* desire that the individual be notified, you can check if he or she has provided a proper means of communication in his or her profile: a blog, website, or email address. If one is present, use those communication channels. We do not need Stack Overflow to be another point of redundancy.

Stack Overflow does not exist to pass messages back and forth, and users that find your question via Google do not want to see a summoning of Jon Skeet in your question. Jon Skeet will see your question, as he sees all questions before they are typed. For other users, we will see them if we are active on the site at the time, and the thousands of extremely knowledgable users will assist you as they are able.

Comment: *Walk over to his cubicle.*... what... and speak to him face to face? We're software engineers ffs.

Comment: Point taken. OK, walk over to his cubicle and speak to his shoes, if you are extroverted enough and happen to work in the same office at the same time. Email and IM otherwise.

Comment: SO you email him , and now you and him have the answer. What about the rest of the world  who had the same problem? @AnthonyPegram

Comment: Read the first paragraph. "By all means, ask the question on SO if you feel it adds value." You have the means for getting the link to your coworker.

Comment: OK, so what would be so wrong with him getting  an automated message in SO instead of me emailing him?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a messaging site. We're not a social network. The SE creators have decided not to reinvent that wheel. You can certainly leave comments on answers, and authors will be notified of such responses, but that's as far as it goes. But again, go back to point #2. We do not want questions to be targetted at specific people, it goes completely against the professional community nature of the website. If *you* want a targetted question, you will simply have to notify the target yourself.