# Share a question to someone else INSIDE Stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, questions, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Routing a question to a particular Stack Overflow member or members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-stack-overflow-member-or-members)

Currently the only options in Stackoverflow to share a question with someone that you think can help you is through:

- email
- Google+
- Twitter
- Facebook

It could be awesome the ability to also share the question to someone INSIDE Stackoverflow, this can be like a notification to the Stackoverflow user that received the request or something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: [What's wrong with providing a (relevant) link to the question as part of a comment or answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147222/175248)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19990/routing-a-question-to-a-particular-stack-overflow-member-or-members ; some users would be swapped with unsolicited notifications.

Comment: Doesn't adding a comment like "@diosney Look at this" fulfil that function? (I don't know; it might not.) Once the comment has been notified to the inbox, after ten minutes or so, it can simply be deleted. But I don't know if you can address arbitrary users this way.

Comment: Wow! What unpopular question I made :D Thanks for the clarification on how this is a bad idea ;)

Comment: I'd say that two downvotes doesn't make it unpopular, it just means that people disagree with your statement.  Anything south of -5, however, may be unpopular.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: It's perfectly fine to share a question that you feel is relevant to an answer you're commenting on, or link to a related or duplicate question. But if you just want to bring attention to an unrelated question in hopes of getting it answered by somebody, **please don't**. I've had to contact and clean up after users who posted *dozens* of comments begging various people to look at their questions.

Comment: Thanks :) It seems that I will be reaching the 5-downvotes threshold veery soon :D

Comment: @Bolt Thanks for the confirmation. I can see another issue where two users have the same display name and neither has previously participated in a question. There's a high chance of spamming.

Comment: I love the double standard here... we don't want to pester our users but its fine to pester people on Facebook of Twitter.  Personally, I think they're all obnoxious and should go away (the links to pester women e to help, not the services. :p).

Comment: Damned phone.....  that should be "pester people", not "pester women".   *sigh*

Comment: @Barak Haha, I actually tried to make sense of that for like 10 seconds. DYAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook, Twitter, and Google+ all have one very important thing in common:  They are social networks. Their goal is completely different than the goal of Stack Exchange, which is to create high-quality content in the form of questions and answers.

While the social networks focus on connecting *people*, Stack Exchange focuses on building high-quality *content* that serves future visitors for years to come. The Stack Exchange system determines what's high quality and what's low quality using the voting system, which Stack Exchange tries really hard to make sure always focuses on content, not people.

Anything that turns Stack Exchange into a social network threatens the very existence of the reputation currency system by moving the focus onto the people instead of the material posted. This could lead to certain individuals having higher reputation, simply because of who that person is instead of what that person posted.

Instead, let the social networks handle the sharing. People and systems do much better at what they specialize in.

As an aside, if there are certain people who you'd like to share posts with, check their profile. Many people are on Twitter, Facebook, Google+, or have blogs or ways to contact them. It wouldn't be unacceptable to tweet a question to your followers, where Jon Skeet just happens to be one of them.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I really like it :) It was very professional. Thanks again.